# How many pickups $K$ should I do to have a $p$% of probability of picking up a divisor of $n$ (if exists) in the interval $[2..\lfloor n/2\rfloor]$?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, factoring

I am trying to understand if it makes sense an algorithm to decide if a given number $n$ is *possibly prime* or not by using the [divisor function bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate) defined by professor Jeffrey Lagarias as:

$\sigma(n)\lt H_n + ln(H_n)e^{H_n}$

where $H_n$ refers to the [Harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

The idea for the algorithm is as follows:

> A given number $n$ is *possibly prime* if and only if when picking up
>   randomly $K$ integers in the interval $[2..\lfloor n/2\rfloor]$ no one
>   of them divides $n$.

The question is:

> How many pickups $K$ should I do so I could have
>   a $p$% of probability of picking up a divisor of $n$ (if
>   exists) in the $[2..\lfloor n/2\rfloor]$ interval?

For instance, $p$% = $80$%.

My idea is that assuming the existing bound for $\sigma(n)$, the probability of finding a factor / divisor of $n$ in $[2..\lfloor n/2\rfloor]$ would be:

$P_n = \frac{H_n + ln(H_n)e^{H_n}}{(n/2)-2}$

But from that point I do not know how to continue... does it makes sense a *possibly prime* algorithm like this one or not? any ideas or comments regarding the topic are very welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not be an efficient algorithm for most interesting numbers. The amount of divisors of $N$ below $N$ can be very small. Say for numbers you care about in RSA you have exactly two divisors of $N$.

Even for very smooth numbers you will be much more likely to pick a non divisor then a divisor. The most problematic issue with your algorithm though is that your bound for $\sigma(n)$ is from the wrong side. You will want to bound your probability of failure (failing to say composite when the number is composite) from below. I.e. you want to be at least $p_K$ sure that $n$ is composite where $K$ is number of attempts and $p_K$ is some probability which goes to 1 as $K$ goes to $\infty$. Since your bound on the number of divisors is from above though you can't bound the probability from below. What you would need is that there is **at least** some amount of divisors of $N$ below $N$ so that when choosing numbers randomly you choose a divisor with probability at least $p$ since there are at least **bound** many divisors. But instead you know that there are **at most** $H_n+\ln(H_n)e^{H_n}$ divisors which only gives you an upper bound on the probability instead of a lower bound.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thank you very much for the comments, if I understand correctly, the problem is not having a bounded smaller area inside the interval in which the probabilities of finding a factor were greater, because picking up a possible factor candidate in that area would make this kind of algorithm useful as some extent (clearly it is not useful for the whole interval when $n$ is very big). That is very interesting, and a good point to review.

Comment: @iadvd Pretty much, though it's a lot worse then it might seem. You are trying to test for primality by attempting to factor. If you were able to get this algorithm you propose to be competitive with current primality testing algorithms this would be a Fields medal type result. Polynomial deterministic algorithms are known for primality testing (though with awful C's) wheras the best factoring algorithms are subexponential.

Comment: well my interest was more theoretical than practical in terms of competitiveness of the algorithm, good point anyway. I like programming primality algorythms, so I wondered if this one deserved to use some time on it. :)

Comment: reviewing some old questions I found this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175748/how-many-distinct-factors-of-n-are-less-than-x